# WindowsFormsHost doesn't resize panel

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

Hi I am trying to host a Panel in a WindowsformsHost control as follows:

```
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
       <WindowsFormsHost Name="FormsHost" Background="Aqua" Height="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <wf:Panel Dock="Fill" x:Name="basePanel" AutoSize="True" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </DockPanel>
```

for some reason the panel doesn't resize when the application does. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you need to bind wfh's Height and Width, same for Panel Dock fill property. Try setting Autosize = false. Also check AutoScaleMode on your panel - should be None.